# Count how many times an object occurs in a list of a list within a DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a DataFrame pd with a column called 'elements' which contains a list of a list of objects as shown below:

```
print(df2['elements'])

0       [Element B, Element Cr, Element Re]
1       [Element B, Element Rh, Element Sc]
2        [Element B, Element Mo, Element Y]
3       [Element Al, Element B, Element Lu]
4       [Element B, Element Dy, Element Os]
```

`Name: elements, Length: 1763, dtype: object`

I would like to count how many times each string within the whole column, so like in the example above the count for the string 'Element B' is 5 or for 'Element Mo' is 1.

I have tried setting up a dictionary below, but this just counts the each list instead of the strings that are in them.

```
elements_count_dict = {}
for entry in df2['elements']:
    for object in entry:
        if object in elements_count_dict:
            elements_count_dict[object] += 1
        else:
            elements_count_dict[object] = 0
```

However, doing it this way the dictionary of tracks each individual character instead of the strings i.e. [ = 5 and ] = 5 and even after converting the column to string using `df2['elements']to_string()` it still doesn't work.

Comment: You say the column contains "a list of a list of objects". Surely, each entry in the column contains either 1 *string*, e.g. `"[Element B, Element Cr, Element Re]"` or a list with *strings*, e.g. `['Element B', 'Element Cr', 'Element Re']`. Please clarify which of these you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as follows:

1. First, use [`Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) to replace `[` and `]` in your strings with `''` (regex: `r\[|\]`).
2. Second, use [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to split the string on `,`  (i.e. `,\s`).
3. Third, use [`Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) to put each item on its own row.
4. Finally, apply [`Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) to return a `pd.Series` with a count for each item in your lists (in order of appearance).

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'elements': {0: '[Element B, Element Cr, Element Re]',
  1: '[Element B, Element Rh, Element Sc]',
  2: '[Element B, Element Mo, Element Y]',
  3: '[Element Al, Element B, Element Lu]',
  4: '[Element B, Element Dy, Element Os]'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

counts = df.elements.str.replace(r'\[|\]','', regex=True)\
    .str.split(',\s').explode().value_counts()

print(counts)

Element B     5
Element Cr    1
Element Re    1
Element Rh    1
Element Sc    1
Element Mo    1
Element Y     1
Element Al    1
Element Lu    1
Element Dy    1
Element Os    1
Name: elements, dtype: int64

# to turn that into a dict, simply use:
# d = counts.to_dict()
```

Answer (score 1):

First use `np.ravel` to flatten the nested list coming from `df.elements.to_list` and then use `collections.Counter` instead of a loop:

```
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

ravel = np.ravel(df.elements.to_list())
Counter(ravel)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it

may not be very elegant, but works

```
df['col1'].str.replace(r'\[|\]','', regex=True).str.split(',').explode().str.strip().to_frame().groupby('col1').value_counts()
```

```
col1
Element Al    1
Element B     5
Element Cr    1
Element Dy    1
Element Lu    1
Element Mo    1
Element Os    1
Element Re    1
Element Rh    1
Element Sc    1
Element Y     1
dtype: int64
```

Data Used

```
data={'col1': {0: '[Element B, Element Cr, Element Re]',
  1: '[Element B, Element Rh, Element Sc]',
  2: '[Element B, Element Mo, Element Y]',
  3: '[Element Al, Element B, Element Lu]',
  4: '[Element B, Element Dy, Element Os]'}}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```